# How to get rows without single max value row

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have table in Oracle SQL. Table contains different values for different objects and I need to select every record except one with max value grouped by objects, but max value can have duplicate record in the table below. I need to use analytical functions.

```
object value
obj1   100
obj1   100
obj1   50
obj1   50
obj2   30
obj2   10
obj2   10
```

So I need all records except single record with max value for each group. For example above my SQL query result must be

```
object value
obj1   100
obj1   50
obj1   50
obj2   10
obj2   10
```

As you can see, result contains all records except two records that have max value per object, but result contains duplicate records of max value.

I tried something like this

```
SELECT * 
FROM (SELECT object, value, max(value) OVER (PARTITION BY object) as maxval FROM table)
WHERE value != maxval
```

But this query returns duplicates of records with max value. Is there any solution with as less subqueries as possible?

Comment: I'm confused.  Why isn't 30 in the results of `obj2`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So I need all records except single record with max value for each group.

You can use window functions:

```
select object, value
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by object, value order by value) as seqnum_ov,
             max(value) over (partition by object) as max_value
      from t
     ) t
where max_value <> value or seqnum_ov > 1
```

Comment: It's better with `seqnum_ov > 1`  but thank you for the idea